# What is the benefit of using entangled photons for ghost imaging compared to just spatial correlated photons?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, experimental-physics, quantum-information, quantum-optics, imaging

I am planning to work in quantum ghost imaging. I will be using a type 2 entangled spdc source which is already there in the lab. I need to know what will be the effect of using polarization entangled, spatially correlated photon spdc source for ghost imaging than just spatially correlated photons or just spatially entangled photons.

I've found that when we are using entangled photons, there is higher signal to noise ratio but I was not able to find any other benefit. Are there any other reasons why entangled photons are beneficial? Please mention the reference

Comment: [This](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.92.033601) might be relevant.

Comment: Just to sound a note of caution: be careful to make a fair comparison when comparing imaging methods. There are a lot of claims in the literature saying why some method is better than another, but many of those claims prove empty when you allow for deconvolution and things like that. A quick way to find out the best that can be done with classical sources is to find out what astronomers and others (e.g. in biophysics) actually do.

Comment: A relevant review paper https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/83960739.pdf

Comment: @Sunyam does that mean that spatially correlated photons and classically correlated photons are same?

Comment: @QuantumOscillator They say that keeping the source same, the ghost imaging using entangled photons can be performed both in the near field as well as the far field. However, with classically  correlated light, again keeping the source same, there is a bound (derived from Fourier uncertainty) on the image resolution at near and field fields.

Comment: This is stated in their introduction "In this Letter we distinguish between classical and
nonclassical aspects of coincidence imaging. In particular, we demonstrate that coincidence images formed with a fixed geometry, including ghost diffraction patterns, do not reveal any distinctly nonclassical behavior. However, the ability to form images with high resolution and high contrast in any plane, without changing the illumination,
is a nonclassical signature [11,13].

Comment: This signature can be expressed as a violation of an inequality, akin to a Bell inequality [14], which we derive below. In the context of
classical wave mechanics, this inequality is manifest in the principle of diffraction. Experimentally, we form coincidence images in the near and far fields of a source
of entangled photons and find that the product of their resolutions is a factor of 3 better than that which is possible according to classical diffraction theory. "